# An error occurred on the always on dashboard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, clustering

I have a setup of Windows Server Failover Cluster and i am using SQL Server Service with one DC, One Primary Server and One Secondary Server.

During Using SQL Server Management Studio, when i click at Show Dashboard Under "Always On High Availability", It shows that error i.e.

**An error occurred on the always on dashboard**

How to resolve this issue ?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se, What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: @RandiVertongen 17.0

Comment: @RandiVertongen Dear i am stuck here from last 3 days. kindly share your views if you have.

Comment: I would try updating ssms, I have been looking for info on the column in the error but can only find a cmdlet that was added in 17.0. I looked through the commands fired when opening the dashboard on my version (17.9) but to no avail

Comment: @RandiVertongen Hi Dear did you find any solution ?

Comment: I installed ssms 17.0 and connected to a SQL 2017 with an availability group, no issue there. Did you try updating ssms? My guess is that it has something to do with the change from `required_copies_to_commit` to `REQUIRED_SYNCHRONIZED_SECONDARIES_TO_COMMIT` in the `sys.availability_groups` dmv altough I cannot find the `required_copies_to_commit` column in older versions

Comment: @RandiVertongen Dear you want to say that after installtion at your end Show Dashboard  is working fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

The issue is due to the dashboard executing queries referencing the `required_copies_to_commit` column from the `master.sys.availability_groups` dmv that was changed to `required_synchronized_secondaries_to_commit`.

The solution is to upgrade SSMS (testing done on the 17.4 version).

### SSMS 17.0

**When retrying this on a machine with SSMS 17.0 installed**

The same error occurs:

> invalid column name `required_copies_to_commit`

[image]

**This is due to the query being different when opening the dashboard on 17.0:**

```
      select * into #tmpag_availability_groups from master.sys.availability_groups
    ...
    SELECT
    CAST(
            serverproperty(N'Servername')
           AS sysname) AS [Server_Name],
    AG.name AS [Name],
    ISNULL(AG.automated_backup_preference, 4) AS [AutomatedBackupPreference],
    ISNULL(AG.failure_condition_level, 6) AS [FailureConditionLevel],
    ISNULL(AG.health_check_timeout, -1) AS [HealthCheckTimeout],
    AR2.replica_metadata_id AS [ID],
    ISNULL(arstates2.role, 3) AS [LocalReplicaRole],
    ISNULL(agstates.primary_replica, '') AS [PrimaryReplicaServerName],
    AG.group_id AS [UniqueId],
    ISNULL(AG.basic_features, 0) AS [BasicAvailabilityGroup],
    ISNULL(AG.db_failover, 0) AS [DatabaseHealthTrigger],
    ISNULL(AG.dtc_support, 0) AS [DtcSupportEnabled],
    ISNULL(AG.is_distributed, 1) AS [IsDistributedAvailabilityGroup],
    ISNULL(AG.cluster_type, 0) AS [ClusterType],
    ISNULL(AG.required_copies_to_commit, 0) AS [RequiredCopiesToCommit]
    FROM
    #tmpag_availability_groups AS AG
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpag_availability_group_states as agstates ON AG.group_id = agstates.group_id
    INNER JOIN #tmpag_availability_replicas AS AR2 ON AG.group_id = AR2.group_id
    INNER JOIN #tmpag_availability_replica_states AS arstates2 ON AR2.replica_id = arstates2.replica_id AND arstates2.is_local = 1
    ORDER BY
    [Name] ASC
   ...
```

**A column that no longer exists is used**

```
ISNULL(AG.required_copies_to_commit, 0) AS [RequiredCopiesToCommit]
```

Instead of the correct column on newer versions of SSMS:

```
ISNULL(AG.required_synchronized_secondaries_to_commit, 0) AS [RequiredSynchronizedSecondariesToCommit]
```

### SSMS 17.4

*Disclaimer: versions 17.1, 17.2 and 17.3 might also show the correct dashboard. I did not test these yet*

**When tracing the queries being run by ssms (17.4 or higher) when the dashboard correctly opens, this query runs**

```
select * into #tmpag_availability_groups from master.sys.availability_groups
        ...    
SELECT
    CAST(
            serverproperty(N'Servername')
           AS sysname) AS [Server_Name],
    AG.name AS [Name],
    ISNULL(AG.automated_backup_preference, 4) AS [AutomatedBackupPreference],
    ISNULL(AG.failure_condition_level, 6) AS [FailureConditionLevel],
    ISNULL(AG.health_check_timeout, -1) AS [HealthCheckTimeout],
    AR2.replica_metadata_id AS [ID],
    ISNULL(arstates2.role, 3) AS [LocalReplicaRole],
    ISNULL(agstates.primary_replica, '') AS [PrimaryReplicaServerName],
    AG.group_id AS [UniqueId],
    CAST(ISNULL(AG.basic_features, 0) AS bit) AS [BasicAvailabilityGroup],
    CAST(ISNULL(AG.db_failover, 0) AS bit) AS [DatabaseHealthTrigger],
    CAST(ISNULL(AG.dtc_support, 0) AS bit) AS [DtcSupportEnabled],
    CAST(ISNULL(AG.is_distributed, 0) AS bit) AS [IsDistributedAvailabilityGroup],
    ISNULL(AG.cluster_type, 0) AS [ClusterType],
    ISNULL(AG.required_synchronized_secondaries_to_commit, 0) AS [RequiredSynchronizedSecondariesToCommit]
    FROM
    #tmpag_availability_groups AS AG
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpag_availability_group_states as agstates ON AG.group_id = agstates.group_id
    INNER JOIN #tmpag_availability_replicas AS AR2 ON AG.group_id = AR2.group_id
    INNER JOIN #tmpag_availability_replica_states AS arstates2 ON AR2.replica_id = arstates2.replica_id AND arstates2.is_local = 1
    ORDER BY
    [Name] ASC
...


 select * into #tmpag_availability_groups from master.sys.availability_groups
```

**SSMS version**

[image]

**(17.4)**

As a side note, some of these columns have not been added to the `sys.availability_groups` [dmv reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-availability-groups-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**In the end, the dashboard opens correctly.**

Due to the correct columnname being used

```
required_synchronized_secondaries_to_commit
```

---

### The solution

You have to upgrade to a higher version (**17.4** worked for me) of SSMS to get the correct and existing DMV columns in the query.

Comment: Dear Thanks for your effort . I have installed 18.0 version & working fine now Cheers :)

Comment: @MubasharIftikhar  happy to help! If my answer helped you solve the question could you mark it as solved? Thanks!

Comment: Sure Dear. I am unable to find the option "mark as solved" but at the top of your answer where i can see '1' when i click on that for vote it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score" .

Comment: i am not a continuous user of StackExchange thats why i can't able to vote and i have no 15 repetitions.
but again thanks for your effort :)
you are great :)

Comment: Read the Documentation , Done :)

Comment: @MubasharIftikhar Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear i have one more issue. During creation of AG at last step, i am facing a error i.e. the following required directories do not exist on replica DBN2 : C:\Program Files \Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLSERVER1\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/235367/sql-server-checking-for-compatibility-of-the-database-file-locations-on-the-serv
here i have describe my problem.