# SQL SERVER Checking for Compatibility of the Database File Locations on the Server Instance that Hosts Secondary Replica

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, ssms

I am using SQL Server 2017 and SSMS 18.0 Version. During creation of availability group at validation step at primary Server (DBN1), i am facing that error i.e.

**the following required directories do not exist on replica DBN2 : C:\Program Files \Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLSERVER1\MSSQL\DATA**
[image]

How to resolve this issue ??

Answer (score -1):

As per `@PinalDave` blog [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/11/23/sql-server-alwayson-wizard-error-checking-compatibility-database-file-locations-server-instance-hosts-secondary-replica/) the wizard looks at the exact same folder path.  Here is the query to find exact path.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id), physical_name FROM SYS.MASTER_FILES;
Go
```

We need to make sure that the path exists on secondary replica, not just drive letter.
Once we created path, issue was resolved, and we were able to move forward.

For further your ref [here](https://shabsql.blogspot.com/2016/08/alwayson-availability-group-create-new.html) and [here](https://www.sqlservergeeks.com/alwayson-availability-group-setup-checking-for-compatibility-of-the-database-file-location-on-the-secondary-replica-resulted-in-an-error/)